Existence of invariant measures for the discrete time Markov chain
I am looking for a rigorous  proof for the  (existence) part of the following  theorem

where here $P_{i,j}$ are the entries of the transition  matrix of the chain and $T_i$ is the hitting time of the state $i$ defined by $$T_i:= \inf\{n\ge1 1: X(n) =i\}$$
In the sketch of the proof given by the author, it is stated that since the chain is
recurrent, the  sum defining $v(j)$ in 2.10 is convergent or (<$\infty$).
I tried to track the proof and I found that (according to the author argument),
we should  prove that if the chain is recurrent, then the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(T_i > n| X(0) =i)\quad \quad (1)$$
is convergent. However, since the chain is recurrent, all what we know is that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(T_i = n| X(0) =i) = P(T_i < \infty | X(0) =i) = 1 $$
but this doesn't imply that the sum (1) converges.
Thank you for any hint or comment.

Recurrence implies that $P(T_i<\infty\mid (X(0)=i) =1$, for each state $i$.
In particular, the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{T_i-1}1(X(n)=j)$ inside the expectation on the right side of (2.1) is finite ($P(\cdot\mid X(0)=i)$-a.s.) because that sum is dominated by $T_i$.
It's not immediately obvious that $\nu(j)$ as defined in (2.10) is finite. But it is true that $\nu P =\nu$; more precisely,
$$
\sum_j\nu(j) P_{j,k} =\nu(k)
$$
for all $k$. This in turn implies by induction that $\nu P^m=\nu$ for $m=1,2,3,\ldots$. Fix a state $j$. By recurrence and irreducibility,   there is a large enough $m$ such that $P^m_{j,i}>0$. Then
$$
1 =\nu(i)=\nu P^m(i) =\sum_k \nu(k)P^m_{k,i}\ge\nu(j)P^m_{j,i},
$$
so $\nu(j)\le 1/P^m_{j,i} <\infty$.
Your sum in (1) is $E(T_i\mid X(0)=i)$, and this will be finite if and only is the chain is positive recurrent. This is the case if and only if the measure $\nu$ has finite total mass.

I appreciate your answer
